# multi-row select, backed by NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, edit

Matt Gallagher wrote a good article on implementing mutli-row selection in a UITableView
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html

I'm looking to implement similar functionality but my data source is an NSFetcedResultsController rather than a simple NSArray.

Has anyone come across such an implementation?

Comment: havent had to do anything like this, but i don't see how it wouldn't be the same as the array once you get the fetched results controller up and running with all its oddities.

Comment: The point is to avoid loading in that whole array at one time ... The biggest advantage to FRC is that when a row/cell/data is offscreen, it can be released and then reloaded on demand, transparently.  Saves a ton of memory when you have lots of data/cells/rows.

Comment: true, since asking the question I've updated my model so that each object has a selected flag..